# SCRIPT5009: 'FormData' não está definido

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

A tag FormData está sendo apresentada indefinida. O IE não reconhece.

```
    var formAnexo = null;
    if ($("#anexarArquivos").attr("enctype") == "multipart/form-data") {
        formAnexo = new FormData($("#anexarArquivos").get(0));
    }
```

Comment: Daniela, pode colocar o seu HTML também para compreendermos melhor a pergunta. E já agora que biblioteca está a usar, e o que é o FormData? um plugin jQuery? MooTools?

Answer (score 1):

[FormData](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#formdata) (que faz parte do [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2))  não é suportado em versões do IE inferiores ao IE10 ou quando você está utilizando algum modo de compatibilidade.

Você pode ver a matriz de suporte [aqui](http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata).

Porém caso você tenha que dar suporte a IE inferiores ao IE10 você pode utilizar o polyfill [jUri.js](https://github.com/3nr1c/jUri.js).

Caso sua página esteja rodando erroneamente em modo de compatibilidade considere informar o IE que você quer usar a última versão colocando a `meta tag` no `head` conforme abaixo:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```